# Handle connections using sockets at four different ports

Tags: c, linux, sockets, select, port

I try to make a client/server system in C on a Linux platform. I want to listen on four different ports. Therefore I create four file descriptors, one for each port. Additionally the process binds the fd to the port and starts listen to it. This works fine.
Further I use `select()` to listen for connections and there I get a problem. In the first run the program waits at select until a client is connected. After I send with telnet a string to the server it continues. But in the second run of the loop the program stops again at select and waits as long as a new client connects. Even if I send a new string via telnet it waits and handles this after a new connection has been established. The example I used is similar to [this link](http://www.binarytides.com/multiple-socket-connections-fdset-select-linux/). 
Therefore I do not use a timeout. 
Why does it wait for a new connection at select? How can I handle this issue?

My code:

```
FD_ZERO(&read_sock);
FD_SET(fd[0], &read_sock);
FD_SET(fd[1], &read_sock);
FD_SET(fd[2], &read_sock);
FD_SET(fd[3], &read_sock);
while(TRUE){
    fprintf(stderr,"Waiting for incoming connections...\n");
    status = select(maxfd+1,&read_sock,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    fprintf(stderr,"Number of fd: %d\n",status);
    if(status>0){
        for(int i=0; i< FD_SET_SIZE; i++){
            if(FD_ISSET(fd[i], &read_sock)){
                fd_accept=accept(fd[i],(struct sockaddr*)&client_address[i], &len);
                 if(client_sock[i] < 0) {
                     client_sock[i] = fd_accept;
                }
                int lenght = recv(client_sock[i],data,BUFFER-1,0);
                if(lenght>0){
                    data[lenght] = '\0';
                    fprintf (stderr,"Received: %s\n", data);
                }else if(lenght==0){
                    getpeername(fd[i],(struct sockaddr*)&client_address[i], &len);
                    close(fd[i]);
                    client_sock[i] = -1;
                }else{
                    fprintf(stderr,"Error: %d\n",errno);
                }

                char string[] = "Test"; //sends a char Test to the client

                write(client_sock[i],&string,sizeof(string));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`select` is a blocking operations. From man page:

```
select() and pselect() allow a program to monitor multiple file descriptors, 
waiting until one or more of the file descriptors become "ready" for some class
of I/O operation (e.g., input possible). A file descriptor is considered ready
if it is possible to perform the corresponding I/O operation (e.g., read(2))
without blocking.
```

Since the descriptors you give it are listener sockets, it will block until there is a new socket on either one.

If you want to listen for data on one of the accepted sockets you need to `select` on the socket descriptor as well, which you store in the `client_address` vector.
Your code effectively listens for new connections, accepts it, reads data, writes something in return and then throws the socket away without closing it.

Comment: That's it! The program from the OP simply waits only for new connections. And it works as expected :-)

Comment: If I understand you right, I have to change the fdmax from the first run to the second to the new fdmax value.

Comment: fdmax might not need change - depends on the descriptor value. But probably, yes. But you also have to `FD_SET` the new descriptor, or select won't consider it.